# How can I extend a method that requires only a new parameter?

Tags: java, methods

lets say we have such a method:

```
public List<Animal> findByKeyword(String keyword){
    List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    // Validate keyword is not null etc..
    // hit db for animals with name like keyword and add to list
    // hit db for animals with owner name like keyword and add to list
    // hit db for animals with nick name like keyword and add to list
    // remove duplicates in the list
    return animals;
 }
```

Assume this method is used in quite a few places and assume it is a bit longer... Well now I want to add a simple boolean something like this:

```
 public List<Animal> findByKeyword(String keyword,boolean excludeDead){
      // code here...
 }
```

The only difference should be something like this:

```
     // remove duplicates in the list 
     // if(excludeDead) removeDeadAnimalsFromTheList
```

So I do not want to copy paste the whole method. But I do not want to add the parameter to the existing method either because the method is used in a lot of places ( where excludeDead = false by default.. Say that this is a new requirement.. )

But the thing is, I do not want to make this change:

```
     // remove duplicates in the list 
     // if(excludeDead) removeDeadAnimalsFromTheList
```

because I am unneccesarily loading all the dead Animals if exludeDead is true.. So what I want to do is to modify:

```
    // hit db for animals with name like keyword and add to list BASED ON THE GIVEN BOOLEAN VALUE
```

What is the best way to extend such piece of code? Is there any way to make the parameter optional?

Please do not assume this is a real code, I just tried to make it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload the method:

```
public List<Animal> findByKeyword(String keyword, boolean excludeDead) {
   // the original code here
   if (excludeDead) {
       // additional code in case excludeDead is true
   }
}

public List<Animal> findByKeyword(String keyword) {
    return findByKeyword(keyword, false);
}
```

Comment: This would be ambiguous and not compile - Note NOT different arguments

Comment: @user2310289: Oh, forgot to remove the boolean argument in the second method. Missed that, sorry. Edited now.

Answer (score 4):

Invoke the second method from the first using a default value

```
public List<Animal> findByKeyword(String keyword){
   return findByKeyword(keyword, false); //your default value
 }

 public List<Animal> findByKeyword(String keyword,boolean excludeDead){
      List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    // Validate keyword is not null etc..
    // hit db for animals with name like keyword and add to list
    // hit db for animals with owner name like keyword and add to list
    // hit db for animals with nick name like keyword and add to list
    // remove duplicates in the list
    return animals;
 }
```

Comment: This is basically what I would suggest. Have the original method call your new method.  Basically, you will "Cut'n'Paste" which is much better than "Copy'n'Paste".

Answer (score 1):

Call the 1st method inside your new implementation, then apply the condition to the result list.

```
public List<Animal> findByKeyword(String keyword, boolean excludeDead){
     List<Animal> list = findByKeyword(keyword);

     // Now apply the condition on the list above.
}
```

Comment: Sorry I completely made my question wrong.. I will edit it. I want to hit the db everytime with the new parameter so I do not load all the dead animals..

Comment: Edited my question. Sorry the first version was not correct. I missed the most important part.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new method as

```
public List<Animal> findByKeyword(String keyword, boolean excludeDead){
    List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    // Validate keyword is not null etc..
    // hit db for animals with name like keyword and add to list
    // hit db for animals with owner name like keyword and add to list
    // hit db for animals with nick name like keyword and add to list
    // remove duplicates in the list
// remove duplicates in the list 
     // if(excludeDead) removeDeadAnimalsFromTheList
    return animals;
 }
```

and call this from your existing method

```
 public List<Animal> findByKeyword(String keyword) {
     return  findByKeyword(keyword,false);
 }
```

Hope this helps.